# MySQL Insert values from multiple table in one table in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL database.

Supposedly I have 3 table.

```
Table A : column ida
Table B : column idb
Table C: column A,B
```

**I want to write a single through which I can insert values from Table A and Table B to Table C ??**

Comment: How are tables A and B related?

Comment: and how do they relate to table C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
insert into tablec
select a.ida, b.idb
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on -- relation between tablea and tableb
```

but you'll have to finish inserting the relation between tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO C SELECT id1, id2 FROM A, B WHERE ...
```

I'm assuming that C has only tow columns and they are of same datatype as that of id1 and id2 from tables A and B. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: where condition for both the tables are different.. Than how to approach?